# Why IEnumerable and why not List with Entity Framework and Linq combination

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

What is the main problem we face while development if I use `List<Employee>` instead of `IEnumerable<Employee>`? Do we get any benefits I am going to have if I use `IEnumerable`.

I worked with ADO.NET mostly I used List directly for storing the result. But when I looked over the Linq queries with Entity Framework, most of the tutorials are using `IEnumerable` itself. I'm not sure why they are using `IEnumerable` and why not `List` ?

```
List<Employee> lstemp = _dbContext.Employees.ToList();

IEnumerable<Employee> emplst = _dbContext.Employees.ToList();
```

Comment: List does implement IEnumerable, so by targeting that the reach is greater

Comment: Practically, I'm not getting your statement. Can you provide any documents or examples which proves IEnumerable prior to the list please

Comment: If an API or method requires an `IEnumerable<T>` as its parameter, you can call it and pass in a `List<T>`, or an `Collection<T>`, or an array  `T[]`. `IEnumerable` makes it more flexible - if you require a `List<T>` for your method - you can **only** call it with a `List<T>` ... (same goes for values being returned from a method)

Comment: @marc_s Not so much for return values - returning `List<T>` doesn't preclude using it generally since it implements `IEnumerable<T>`. So you can return more specifically if you prefer.

Comment: For example, using `AsEnumerable()` on a LINQ to database query means the query can use its internal result storage and just return the objects, but using `ToList()` requires converting to a `List<T>` which may create a copy of the results in the `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in execution between:

```
List<Employee> lstemp = _dbContext.Employees.ToList();

IEnumerable<Employee> emplst = _dbContext.Employees.ToList();
```

`List<T>` extends `IEnumerable<T>`. Where things change a bit are when you do something like:

```
IEnumerable<Employee> lstemp = _dbContext.Employees.ToList();   

IEnumerable<Employee> emplst = _dbContext.Employees.AsEnumerable();
```

In this case the first example will execute the query immediately and materialize the results. The second will execute the query the instant the emplst instance is enumerated, that is, "touched" by something. So for instance if you had this code in a method that returned the resulting `IEnumerable<T>`, then the query would not run until the caller actually wanted to do something with it, such as a `foreach` or `.Any()` etc. This is called Deferred Execution.

This can lead to some behavior considerations to keep in mind, for instance:

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
{
    using var context = new AppDbContext();
    IEnumerable<Employee> results = context.Employees.ToList();
    return results;
}
```

This is "safe". However,

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
{
    using var context = new AppDbContext();
    IEnumerable<Employee> results = context.Employees.AsEnumerable();
    return results;
}
```

This is not. The reason it is unsafe is that the DbContext instance (context) is scoped to this method via the `using`. Using `AsEnumerable()` does not execute the query, so we return the `IEnumerable<Employee>` results to the caller. When the caller tries to do anything with it, we would receive an exception because the DbContext has been disposed. Methods like that can work only if the DbContext's scope is shared between the method and it's caller.

Typically you will see methods or variable declarations and such use `IEnumerable<T>` or `ICollection<T>` or `IList<T>` rather than concrete classes like `List<T>`. This is because it is generally better to expose sets based on how you intend them to be used rather than by concrete types. The consumer only needs to know how to consume the resulting data, not specifics of how it is stored. However, it's important to know what EF is doing behind the scenes when executing a query so it's clear when that query is expected to be executed.